# Finding square root without division and initial guess

Tags: algorithms

I am trying to look for a division-free algorithms which finds square-root using only addition and multiplication operations, with the initial guess as the number itself. Is there any such algorithms ?

Comment: For what type of numbers? Integers? Floating point?

Comment: I was looking for the most general case, that is floating point. But if there is for integers refer to me that. Atleast I'll have some cases covered.

Comment: Do you consider a bitshift to be division?

Comment: Yes. Actually my constraints are too much tight. This problem arises in the context of encryption, where the encrypted numbers have + and * are valid operations but loses all other usual operations like division, comparison and more importantly the encrypted numbers are not ordered set.

Comment: You can't do comparison?  That's not mentioned in the question.  How is it that you can multiply these numbers but not compare them?

Comment: Please mention in the question all constraints on the solution, including that you can't compare intermediate values (if that is a constraint).  Can you do any conditional branches or do you require straight-line code?  Can you use lookup tables?  What algorithms have you already considered?  Wikipedia has an article on algorithms for computing square roots, listing many methods: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots.  Have you looked at them?  Can you clarify why you've rejected the ones there?

Comment: I'm closing this question because as it stands, it's too broad. Please **edit the question** to include **all** the constraints that apply. Give some idea of what you need this for, too, this may help if you forget to state a constraint precisely. Once you've done that, we can reopen the question. Please take care of not invalidating the existing answers. If the existing answers don't work for you, edit the question in such a way that they remain valid, then ask a new question with your actual constraints.

Answer (score 10):

OK, let's go with floating point. Any positive floating point number is of the form $m \times 2^e$ where $m$ is in the range $[1,2)$ and $e$ is an integer.

If $e$ is even, then:

$$\sqrt{m \times 2^{2p}} = \sqrt{m} \times 2^p$$

And if $e$ is odd, then:

$$\sqrt{m \times 2^{2p+1}} = \sqrt{m} \times \sqrt{2} \times 2^p$$

We can precompute $\sqrt{2}$. So we have reduced the problem to finding a square root of a number between 1 and 2. So far, so good.

We could use the Newton-Raphson method for square roots, but you specifically didn't want division, and it's a bad idea anyway; division is more expensive than multiplication on a modern FPU.

But we could use the Newton-Raphson method for *reciprocal* square roots. The iteration looks like this. If $x_0$ is an initial approximation to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}$, then iterate:

$$x_{i+1} = \frac{1}{2} x_i \left( 3 - m x_i^2 \right)$$

When this has converged, $m x_k$ is an approximation to $\sqrt{m}$. No divisions here, and the problem is now just to come up with an initial estimate.

But wait, we can do better.

Given $b_0 = m$, let's suppose we could come up with a sequence of numbers $Y_i$ such that $b_i = b_0 Y_0^2 Y_1^2 \cdots Y_n^2$ approaches $1$. Then $x_i = b_0 Y_0 \cdots Y_{i-1}$ approaches $\sqrt{m}$ and $y_i = Y_0 \cdots Y_{i-1}$ approaches $\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}$. Please pause for a moment and convince yourself that this is the case.

We already know such a sequence, because we can use the Newton-Raphson iteration for reciprocal square roots:

$$b_i = b_{i-1} Y_{i-1}^2$$
$$Y_i = \frac{1}{2}(3 - b_i)$$

And so:

$$x_0 = m Y_0$$
$$x_{i} = x_{i-1} Y_i$$

and:

$$y_0 = Y_0$$
$$y_{i} = y_{i-1} Y_i$$

But observe that $b_i = x_{i-1} y_{i-1}$. So we don't actually have to retain $b_i$:

$$Y_i = \frac{1}{2}(3 - x_{i-1} y_{i-1}) = 1 + \frac{1}{2}(1 - x_{i-1} y_{i-1})$$

Substituting this into the equations for $x_i$ and $y_i$ gives:

$$x_{i} = x_{i-1} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2}(1 - x_{i-1} y_{i-1}) \right) = x_{i-1} + \frac{1}{2}(1 - x_{i-1} y_{i-1}) x_{i-1}$$
$$y_{i} = y_{i-1} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2}(1 - x_{i-1} y_{i-1}) \right) = y_{i-1} + \frac{1}{2}(1 - x_{i-1} y_{i-1})y_{i-1}$$

Removing the redundant computation gives:

$$r_i = \frac{1}{2}(1 - x_{i-1} y_{i-1})$$
$$x_{i} = x_{i-1} + r_i x_{i-1}$$
$$y_{i} = y_{i-1} + r_i y_{i-1}$$

But we're not done! We can save the multiplication by a half by substituting $h_i = \frac{1}{2} y_i$.

Given $Y$ as an approxmiation to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}$, set:

$$x_0 = m Y$$
$$h_0 = \frac{1}{2} Y$$

Iterate:

$$r_i = \frac{1}{2} - x_{i-1} h_{i-1}$$
$$x_{i} = x_{i-1} + r_i x_{i-1}$$
$$h_{i} = h_{i-1} + r_i h_{i-1}$$

Then $x_i$ converges to $\sqrt{m}$ and $h_i$ converges to $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{m}}$. Not only does the inner loop have no divisions, it can be implemented on modern FPUs using three fused multiply-adds and nothing else. Perhaps it's unsurprising that this algorithm, known as Goldschmidt's algorithm, is the one used in your FPU.

The final question: How do we come up with $Y$? Well, you could use $\frac{1}{m}$ or something if you want to allow one division. But you said no divisions. So since $m$ is known to be between 1 and 2, you could use its high-order bits to consult a lookup table, or use an [interpolating polynomial approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation), such as a Chebyshev polynomial. I'll leave the details of that to you.

Comment: I almost wonder if, after `sqrt(m)*sqrt(2)*2^p`, then a binary search to find `sqrt(m)` would be faster and simpler.

Comment: No, and there's a simple proof. The comparison in binary search returns one bit of information. An IEEE 754 binary32 floating point number has 23 bits of significand to find. Therefore you need at least 23 comparisons to get a square root that way.

Comment: I started wondering when I saw you needed the Newton-Raphson iteration to converge, which sounds a lot more expensive than 23 comparisons.  I didn't really understand much beyond that, but see now it appears to be a shortcut... that still requires converging.

Comment: Why is the initial range reduction to [1,2) using precomputed sqrt(2) necessary/advantageous?  Can we just omit that part?

Comment: @DonHatch The theoretical advantages of using $[1.2)$ are a) they can literally be read off the floating point representation by simply ignoring the mantissa, and b) the domain is smaller than $[1,4)$ and thus you can get a more accurate polynomial approximation of the same degree. This only confers a practical advantage if it reduces the number of iterations by one.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of finding the square root of x, find the square root of 1/x, then multiply by x. Newton iteration for this function gives a formula without divisions.

For an initial value of the iteration, look how floating point numbers are represented as bits, and find a bit pattern that represents a number close to the square root of 1/x.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I strictly didn't want any manipulation with the initial guess. Infact I have done the same thing you suggested, and I found an interesting result in this approach. If $x<1$ the initial guess as $x$ is stable for finding inverse of a square root, and for $x>1$ the initial guess as $1/x$ is stable. But my problem has encrypted numbers so I can't do any sort of division or comparison.

Comment: You better explain what you actually want to achieve, which doesn’t seem to be “calculate a square root”. And manipulating bits in a number x in a deterministic way to get a number y is not “guessing”.